# Executing a system stored procedure (sys.sp_helptext) from a client app without a user wrapper proc

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I would like to create a C# method that accepts one parameter, the name of a stored procedure. The method will then execute the following system stored procedure directly without using a user-defined sub routine to wrap this call.

```
sys.sp_helptext 'proc name'
```

I get the error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'sys.sp_help_text

Is this a permissions issue (I am Admin of my test db) or qualification issue?

```
public static string GetStoredProcedure(string objectName, string connectionString)
{

    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection())
    {
        sqlConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("sys.sp_help_text", sqlConnection);
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@objname", objectName);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        return DataTableToString(ds.Tables[0]);;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no issue, just named wrong

try

```
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("sys.sp_helptext", sqlConnection);
```

instead of

```
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("sys.sp_help_text", sqlConnection);
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably must connect to database with a login with some more privileges. try executing this sp from managment studio after you login with same account your app is using.